# Mongoose unique validation error type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using this schema with `mongoose 3.0.3` from npm:

```
var schema = new Schema({

    _id: Schema.ObjectId,
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true}

});
```

If I try to save a email that is already in db, I expect to get a `ValidationError` like if a `required` field is omitted. However this is not the case, I get a `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index`.

Which is not a validation error (happens even if I remove the unique:true).

Any idea why?

Comment: Side note: `latest npm mongoose` might be meaningless in week/month/year. Put the version you are using.

Comment: It kept doing it even after you removed unique: true because like alexjamesbrown said, that specification creates an index on your DB. That DB and index persist until you drop the index or the DB.  You probably already understood that, but I figured calling that out might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I prefer putting it in path validation mechanisms, like

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function(value, done) {
    this.model('User').count({ email: value }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        } 
        // If `count` is greater than zero, "invalidate"
        done(!count);
    });
}, 'Email already exists');
```

Then it'll just get wrapped into `ValidationError` and will return as first argument when you call `validate` or `save` .

Comment: This is the correct answer. It should be a custom validator for the path, not a pre-save function.

Comment: This works but using this.model can throw an error in certain scenarios when this doesn't refer to a document/instance of the model, but the actual model itself. The safe way to handle all scenarios and avoid throwing an error is to use mongoose.model('User', UserSchema) instead.

Comment: @user3344977 why is this better than a pre-save function?

Comment: @JasonAllan I honestly don't remember and haven't been using mongoose for a long time now. I really should have provided more detail in my comment sorry.

Comment: Above code is giving **DeprecationWarning**:  *collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version*

Answer (score 19):

I had some issues with the approved answer. Namely:

1. `this.model('User')` didn't work for me.
2. the callback `done` wasn't working properly.

I resolved those issues by:

```
  UserSchema.path('email').validate(async (value) => {
    const emailCount = await mongoose.models.User.countDocuments({email: value });
    return !emailCount;
  }, 'Email already exists');
```

I use `async/await` which is a personal preference because it is much neater: https://javascript.info/async-await.

Let me know if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 12):

This is expected behavior

The `unique: true` is equivalent to setting an index in mongodb like this:

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex( { "email": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

To do this type of validation using Mongoose (Mongoose calls this complex validation- ie- you are not just asserting the value is a number for example), you will need to wire in to the pre-save event:

```
mySchema.pre("save",function(next, done) {
    var self = this;
    mongoose.models["User"].findOne({email : self.email},function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            done(err);
        } else if(results) { //there was a result found, so the email address exists
            self.invalidate("email","email must be unique");
            done(new Error("email must be unique"));
        } else {
            done();
        }
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: Tried your method but encountered another issue : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582862/mongoose-pre-save-async-middleware-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 1):

Simply response to json

```
try {
  let end_study_year = new EndStudyYear(req.body);
  await end_study_year.save();
   res.json({
    status: true,
    message: 'បានរក្សាទុក!'
   })
  }catch (e) {
   res.json({
   status: false,
   message: e.message.toString().includes('duplicate') ? 'ទិន្នន័យមានរួចហើយ' : e.message.split(':')[0] // check if duplicate message exist
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering an old question. After testing I feel good to have find these answers, so I will give my experience. Both top answers are great and right, just remember that:

- if your document is new, you can just validate if count is higher than 0, thats the common situation;
- if your document is NOT new and has modified the `unique` field, you need to validate with 0 too;
- if your document is NOT new and has NOT being modified, just go ahead;

Here is what I made in my code:

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(async function validateDuplicatedEmail(value) {
    if (!this.isNew && !this.isModified('email')) return true;

    try {
        const User = mongoose.model("User");

        const count = await User.countDocuments({ email: value });
        if (count > 0) return false;

        return true;
    }
    catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}, "Email already exists");
```