# Mongoose pre.save() async middleware not working as expected

Tags: node.js, validation, mongodb, mongoose

Following up from : [Mongoose unique validation error type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580589/mongoose-unique-validation-error-type/13581906#13581906)

I'm using this schema with `mongoose 3.0.3` from npm:

```
var schema = new Schema({

    _id: Schema.ObjectId,
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true}

});
```

With this middleware to get a validationError from unique:true

```
schema.pre("save", function(next, done) {
    var self = this;

    model.findOne({email : this.email}, 'email', function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            done(err);
        } else if(results) {
            console.warn('results', results);
            self.invalidate("email", "email must be unique");
            done(new Error("email must be unique"));
        } else {
            done();
        }
    });

    next();
});
```

However, it does not work!

`Users.create()` will still return a a `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index` and the `console.warn()` is only called after that.

The save action should not be called until all middleware `done()`have been called according to the docs, and I should get back a validation error.

It looks like the `done()` behavior is not working as expected,

Any idea why?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You're using a parallel middleware callback function (with both `next` and `done`), but you're not setting the parallel flag in the `schema.pre` parameters so it's using the serial rules.

So either include the parallel flag in your call:

```
schema.pre("save", true, function(next, done) { ...
```

Or switch to a serial middleware callback style if that's all you need anyway:

```
schema.pre("save", function(next) {
    var self = this;

    model.findOne({email : this.email}, 'email', function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            next(err);
        } else if(results) {
            console.warn('results', results);
            self.invalidate("email", "email must be unique");
            next(new Error("email must be unique"));
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of Mongoose does this apply to? I can't find any docs on this parallel signature for `schema.pre` that you are using in your code snippet.

Comment: @PeterLyons The parallel option has been around back to 2.x at least.  See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html for the docs.

Comment: @JohnnyHK can I send status code in next() ? If I want to reject the request, that is not save the request in database, and send a status code? is it possible?