# mongoose-unique-validator detects all inputs as already existed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a unique email value in MongoDB. I used mongoose-unique-validator to implement that but resulted in error claiming that my unique emails that I just inputted are already existed.

This is the error message I received from trying to input unique email.

> "message": "User validation failed: email: Error, expected **email** to be
>   unique., **_id**: Error, expected _id to be unique."

They said the **Email** and **_id** are not unique. But.., **_id** is an auto-generated value to be unique in MongoDB meaning that it should not be detected as a duplicated value.

I am not sure if that was caused by my own implementation so I would look forward to see any assumption or ways to debug to the root cause of this too. I tried restarting from fresh Mongo DB and manually inputting uniquely via Postman but still no hope.

These are a part of the codes that might be related to the data creation on MongoDB

**UserModel.js**

```
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UsersSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true},
  hashedPassword: String,
  salt: String,
});

UsersSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: 'Error, expected {PATH} to be unique.' });
UsersSchema.set('autoIndex', false);
```

**Server.js ---- /api/users/register**

```
const finalUser = new Users(user);
finalUser.setPassword(user.password);

finalUser.save((err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json(err)
  }
  return res.json({ user: finalUser.toAuthJSON() })
})
```

---

**Additional Information**

I tried this solution from [Sritam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580589/mongoose-unique-validation-error-type) to detect another email with the same value but it still claims that the inputted email is already existed.

```
UsersSchema.path('email').validate(async (value) => {
  const emailCount = await mongoose.models.User.countDocuments({email: value });
  return !emailCount;
}, 'Email already exists');
```

> "message": "User validation failed: email: Email already exists"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue and solution!

They are acting weird like in the question because the model was not initialized.
I must perform Schema.init() before performing any model validation.

The solution is to add `UsersSchema.init().then(() => {...your operation})`

Now **Server.js ---- /api/users/register** should look like this.

```
Users.init().then(() => {   // where Users is my UsersModel
  finalUser.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json(err)
    }
    return res.json({ user: finalUser.toAuthJSON() })
  })
})
```

Hope this helps other developers who experience similarly odd error!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `validateModifiedOnly` option in [Document.save()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save). `_id` and `email` fields will never be validated unless they are modified. The code should look like this:

```js
finalUser.save({ validateModifiedOnly: true }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json(err)
  }
  return res.json({ user: finalUser.toAuthJSON() })
})
```